# How to send SQL queries to a computer outside of the network through port?

Tags: sql, networking, jdbc, port

I have a java program that uses SQL queries. The goal is to send them from my home PC to a workstation on a different network elsewhere. 
The SQL server is on Windows Server and I opened port 1433 for inbound connections.  From that computer, I can successfully ping the port. However, I can't ping the port from the public ip address, only the local (192.168...), so it doesn't work if I were to try to ping it from my home computer.

Is there a way that I can ping it from my home computer? If so, how would I specify the address for JDBC?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more a network admin question. You'll need to make your database server publicly accessible over the internet (which is a very insecure and a **bad** idea), or arrange to be able to VPN into your corporate network from home so it is as if your home PC is inside the corporate network.

Comment: No worries, I understand it is a bad idea. It is a small company and the server is new, and we only want to do so to do testing and close it later. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Closing it later may already be too late if your system was compromised during that testing phase. Being a small company is not an excuse to do unsafe things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Windows Server is behind an internet gateway/router. You need to configure the gateway to allow and forward inbound connections to TCP port 1433 to the IP of the computer that has SQL Server installed.

Here are some guides that explain how to enable port forwarding on different devices:

- [How to Forward Ports on Your Router](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829) (lifewire.com)
- [How to Port Forward](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) (No-IP.com)

Also, note that we can ping IP addresses, not ports.